# add tkinter variable via function to dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, tkinter

I created a function to add labels (or other tkinter elements to a specific frame). The same function also adds a tkinter variable to a dictionary for better access within the program. Now, there are more than  200 variables within the dictionary and i decided to split them to settings and parameters.

How can i tell the function to eiter add the variable to the settings-dict (my_settings) or to add it to parameters-dict (my_params)?

```
import tkinter as tk

masterframe = tk.Tk()

my_settings = dict()    # unused
my_params   = dict()

def add_label(frame, key, default=None): 
    my_params[key] = tk.StringVar()
    my_params[key].set(default)
    inputframe=tk.Frame(frame)
    inputframe.pack(side='top', padx=5, pady=5, fill='x')
    label = tk.Label(inputframe, text=key, width=10)
    label.pack(side='left')
    label = tk.Label(inputframe, textvariable=my_params[key], width=10)
    label.pack(side='left')
    
add_label(masterframe, 'a', '123')
add_label(masterframe, 'b', '456')
add_label(masterframe, 'c', '789')

masterframe.mainloop()
```

Comment: what is it that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a group parameter to `add_label`. I've used 'p' for params and 's' for settings, but it can be anything. It then uses an if statement to determine which dictionary to add it to.

```
def add_label(frame, key, group, default=None):
    if group == 'p':
        d = my_params
    elif group == 's':
        d = my_settings
    d[key] = tk.StringVar()
    d[key].set(default)
    inputframe=tk.Frame(frame)
    inputframe.pack(side='top', padx=5, pady=5, fill='x')
    label = tk.Label(inputframe, text=key, width=10)
    label.pack(side='left')
    label = tk.Label(inputframe, textvariable=d[key], width=10)
    label.pack(side='left')
    
add_label(masterframe, 'a', 'p', '123')
add_label(masterframe, 'b', 's', '456')
add_label(masterframe, 'c', 's', '789')
```

Comment: I think this is a better and more flexible solution.Unfortunately it is not possible to pass the dictionaries name as an argument to the function.Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?:

```py
import tkinter as tk

masterframe = tk.Tk()

my_settings = dict()
my_params   = dict()

def add_label(frame, key, default=None, setting=False):
    # If the keyword setting is True, `my_settings` will be updated. Otherwise `my_params` will be updated.
    var = tk.StringVar()
    var.set(default)
    inputframe=tk.Frame(frame)
    inputframe.pack(side='top', padx=5, pady=5, fill='x')
    label = tk.Label(inputframe, text=key, width=10)
    label.pack(side='left')
    label = tk.Label(inputframe, textvariable=var, width=10)
    label.pack(side='left')

    # Append it to the dict
    if setting:
        my_settings.update({key: var})
    else:
        my_params.update({key: var})


add_label(masterframe, 'a', '123')
add_label(masterframe, 'b', '456')
add_label(masterframe, 'c', '789')
add_label(masterframe, 'setting', '789', setting=True)

print(my_params)
print(my_settings)

masterframe.mainloop()
```

I think you should look at some `dict` tutorials.